# Sqlite file is missing in iOS TestFlight builds

Tags: swift, app-store, testflight

I have a dictionary app with a preloaded local SQlite database. The app works well in both Debug and Release configuration on Simulator or Device.

But when I uploaded it to TestFlight, the SQLite file seemed to be missing, because the size of the build appears to be 2.6 MB, but my SQLite file is about 70MB+

I used the following code to connect SQLite database.

```swift
let future = Future<Void, Error> { [weak self, weak bgQueue] promise in
    bgQueue?.sync {
        guard let path = Bundle(identifier: bundleIdentifier)?.url(forResource: resourceName, withExtension: "sqlite3")?.absoluteString else {
            promise(.failure(RepoError.invalidFilePath)) // <-- error happens in TF
            return
        }

        do {
            self?.db = try Connection(path, readonly: true)
            promise(.success(()))
        } catch let error {
            promise(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the followings but no luck:

- debug with Release configuration
- check the archived build size is 12.2MB
- check target membership is ticked
- changed absoluteString to path
- check the file in Copy Bundle Resources(Build Phases)

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What about the size of the archive before uploading to TestFlight? Is it 2.6 or 70+ Mb?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev 12.2 MB

Comment: Your code to get the path to the sqlite file is wrong. Replace the use of `absoluteString` with `path`.  I’m assuming Connect wants a file path and not a file URL.

Comment: @HangarRash I just uploaded a new TF build but still get the error, but thanks for advice

Comment: Inspect the contents of the `.xcarchive` package. Inside it, find the `.app` package and check if the sqlite file file is in there. If it's not, check the archive logs to see whether it gets copied to the bundle.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. It was caused by **Development Assets**, my database file somehow added to Target Development Assets, so it was ignored by archiving